# Homeomorphism between $L^p$-spaces on metric spaces and $L^p$-spaces on Euclidean space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, integration, metric-spaces

**Setup:**

---

Fix $p \in [1,\infty)$.
Let $(X,d_X,x_0)$ and $(Y,d_Y,y_0)$ be complete [pointed metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Pointed_metric_spaces) and $\mu$ be Borel.  Let $E^n,E^D$ be Euclidean spaces of respetive dimensions $n$ and $D$ and suppose that $f_1:(X,d_X)\rightarrow E^D$ and $f_2:E^n\rightarrow (Y,d_Y)$ are homeomorphisms satisfying
$$
f_1(x_0)=0 \mbox{ and } f_2(0)=y_0
.
$$

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $(X,d_X)$ Define the $L^p$-like space $L^p_{loc}(X,Y;\mu)$ as being the set of all measurable functions $f$ for which
$$
\int_{x \in K} d^p_Y(f(x),f(x_0)) \mu(dx)<\infty,
$$
for every compact subset $K\subseteq X$.

Suppose that $X$ admits a countable cover of compact sets $\{K_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.  Then this can be made into a complete metric space (standard result) when endowed with the metric
$$
d(f,g)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^n}\sqrt[p]{\int_{x \in K_n} d^p_Y(f(x),g(x)) \mu(dx)}
.
$$
Let $L^p(E^D;E^n;\nu)$ denote the [Bochner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space)-space of all $\nu$-measurable functions from $E^D$ to $E^n$.  Denote by $f^{\star}(\mu)$ the [push-forward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula) on $E^D$.

**Question:**

---

1) Is the map $F$, defined by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
F: L^p_{loc}(X,Y;\mu)&\rightarrow L^p_{loc}(E^D;E^n;f^{\star}(\mu))\\
 f &\mapsto 
f_2\circ f\circ f_1,
\end{aligned}
$$
a homeomoprhism?

2) Are the continuous functions dense in this space?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking for a linear homeomorphism between these $L^p$-spaces, or merely a homeomorphism between the underlying topological spaces?

Comment: Just for the record: all separable Banach spaces are homeomorphic. Proving that your space is homeomorphic to $L^p$ does not seem to be very useful if you do not know anything about the homeomorphism.

Comment: As an example, suppose $X$ is $[0,1]$ with he usual metric and Lebesgue measure.  Suppose $d_Y$ is a bounded metric.  (I assume $d_Y^p$ should be inside the integrals.)  But then $L^p(X,Y;\mu)$ is all measurable functions.  And I guess $d(f,g)$ is a metric for convergence in measure.  So perhaps in that case your space does not depend on $p$?

Comment: My comment has $d_Y$ a bounded metric and $\mu$ a finite measure.  Think about that case.

Comment: I guess in the definition of $d(x,y)$ the integral should be in the power $1/p$. Also some restrictions on $p$ like $p\ge 1$ are needed.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Ofcourse,  I put in those important details.

Comment: I think 2 can be show with Lusin's theorem?